# How to run a simple C++ program in (C++ Builder 10.4.2)

Tags: c++

I have just installed [RAD Studio (C++ Builder 10.4.2)], but I can't even run the (Hello world)
program, it always gives me the following error message:

```
Compiling Foot2Meter.cbproj (Debug, Win32)
[MakeDir Error] Unable to create directory "C:\Users\Public\Documents\Embarcadero\Studio\21.0\hpp\Win32". Could not find file 'C:\Users\Public\Documents\Embarcadero\Studio\21.0\hpp\Win32'.
Failed
Elapsed time: 00:00:02.2
```

this directory (...\hpp\win32) ,doesn't even exists, so how to solve this issue, please?

Comment: The first question to answer is "Does `C:\Users\Public` exist?" If not, you won't have permission in `C:\Users` to create it. Also add what version of windows (presumably 10, but could be 11 or even 7 for that matter).